# Forma correcta listado generico común

Tags: java

Hasta ahora estaba haciendo pequeños programas "sin" utilizar genéricos y entonces creaba diversas clases de listados, como por ejemplo, ListadoClientes, ListadoVehículos, etc. Ahora me he decidido, estando estudiando los genéricos, a hacer un programa de la siguiente forma para evitar tantas clases de listados.
He creado una clase común llamada Listado que es la siguiente:

```
public class Listado<E> implements Iterable<E>,Serializable{
private final List<E> listado;

public Listado(){
    listado=new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<E> getListado(){
    return listado;
}

public int size(){
    return listado.size();
}

public void add(E e){
    listado.add(e);
}


public void listar(){
    for(E e:listado){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

}
```

Y entonces he creado otra clase llamada Agencia donde creo los listados y que me sirve de base para obtener cualquier dato de los mismos.

```
public class GestorAgencia {
private Scanner sc;
private int opcion;
private Listado<Cliente> lc;
private Listado<Vehiculo> lv;
 ......
```

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero hacer un método en la clase de los listados que se refiera a un tipo particular como puede ser cliente, como el siguiente método:

```
public Cliente get(String s){
    for(Cliente c:getListado()){
        System.out.println(c);
        if(c.getDni().equals(s)){
            return c;
        }          
    }
    return null;
}
```

Así pues, mi pregunta es, este método donde colocarlo o como. En la clase Listado mediante streams ?, en otra clase que extendiera Listado?, etc. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Esta función `public Cliente get(String s)` estaría dentro de la clase `Listado` ??? y tu quieres que dicha función sea genérica también?? es decir te traiga un elemento sea el caso de Cliente, Vehículo u otra clase??

Comment: te complicaste de mas compa, todas las listas ya implementan iterable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Si no veo para que crear una clase mas. Java.util.ArrayList (con su Interfaz List) ya hace 90% de lo que quieres.

Luego si quieres encontrar un listado especial usa stream() con findFirst() o findAny(). Hasta puedes hacerlo en paralelo con parallelStream()

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto que crear tu propia clase genérica en lugar de utilizar las colecciones de la API de Java puede serte de utilidad para incorporar funcionalidad específica para tu aplicación, pero en este caso te recomendaría utilizar un nombre descriptivo para la clase, en la medida que lo permita la lógica de los objetos que puede "listar". Sin saber más sobre la "lógica de negocio" de la aplicación que tienes entre manos, parece que un programa que trabaja con vehículos, clientes, etc. podría definir esa clase genérica con el nombre `ListadoRecursos<E>` o `AssetsList<E>`.

Tu propuesta de incluir un método `get(String s)` que atiende a las particularidades del "tipo parametrizado" en Listado parece buena. Podrías incluir control condicional que evalúe el tipo recibido y despliegue lógica específica —tan específica como necesites— según el objeto. Así, por ejemplo, puedes verificar que el elemento de la lista es de tipo `Cliente` antes de realizar la comparación de su DNI y devolver el cliente que corresponda. Esto no parece muy específico o diferente de comparar, por ejemplo, strings con matrículas de objetos `Vehiculo`, pero si la variedad de tus modelos de objetos, lo que antes he llamado "assets" se complica, entonces el control condicional en `get()` puede ser más elaborado.

```java
public E get(String s) {
    for (E e : listado) {
        if (e instanceof Cliente) {
            Cliente cliente = (Cliente) e;
            if (cliente.getDni().equals(s)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: usar instanceof es un codesmell ya que indica que no estas usando la herencia como debieras

Comment: Primero que nada agradecer los comentarios y las respuestas, aparte de también aprender de vosotros. Entonces la segunda pregunta seria. Tras insertar dicho método en clases hijas, ¿sería posible obtener dicho método desde la clase Listado (padre)?

Comment: ¿Hijas de quién? No hay herencia en tu planteamiento. Podría haberla, cabría definir una superclase Asset, por ejemplo, de la que Vehiculo y Cliente fueran subtipos. Pero no has descrito un diseño semejante. No has escrito extends. Tu clase Listado es una Clase Genérica, que recibe como tipo parametrizado <E> alguno de los objetos de los que hablamos. Esto es diferente de herencia. Así las cosas, el método get() lo invocas de un objeto Listado<E>, no de un objeto Vehiculo, Cliente, etc.

Comment: Hola  alejandroMAD. La clase Listado seria padre y crearía una clase hijo que extends Listado para cada una de las clases (ListadoCliente, etc) donde insertaría métodos como el indicado. Entonces la pregunta sería si desde la clase Listado podría acceder a las clases hijas para utilizar sus métodos.